# Спрашивать прерзаписать ли файлы при разархивации, если они отличаются от сущестующих?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

Я создаю архив исполюзуя полные имена файлов. После этого содержиние некоторых файлов может измениться. Использую `tar -C / -xvf back_up.tar` чтоб файлы разархивировались по тем же путям что они были раньше. Насколько я понял зархивированые файлы заменяют существующие.
Как сделить так что, если существующий файл отличается от файла в архиве то выводилось подтверждение о пререзаписи?
`tar -df back_up.tar -C /` - файлы которые изменились, но команда выводит два раза имя

`home/user/111: Mod time differs`
`home/vladimir/111:Size differs`

Comment: Если у файла изменились несколько атрибутов (размер, время, владелец, права и т.п.), то `tar -d` выводит сообщение про каждый изменившийся атрибут. Кстати, почему вы уверены, что /home/user/111 и /home/vladimir/111 это один и тот же файл? У них одинаковый inode? (посмотреть можно командой `ls -i`)

Comment: Что касается сути вопроса (*`"Как сделить так что, если существующий файл отличается от файла в архиве то выводилось подтверждение о пререзаписи?"`*), то (возможно, я чего-то не знаю о tar-е) imho вам надо 1) из вывода `tar -d` сформировать файл с именами файлов, которые изменились (скажем, Names) 2) запустить `tar -C / -xvf back_up.tar -T Names -w` (-w это запрашивать, -T брать извлекаемые имена из файла). / Очевидно, что если файл не менялся, то восстанавливать его смысла нет)